# Use css to specify image dimensions in boot store wp site?

Tags: css, wordpress, image, dimensions

I ran a gtmetrix.com analysis on my website and it said that I needed to specify image dimensions on some of the images. The link to that is: http://gtmetrix.com/reports/whiztoy.com/IxSgh6L2                                                                                                                                                                                    How do I use css to do that? I checked the css file but can't locate the exact tags.

Answer (score 0):

If you html is:

```
<img src="./myimage.png" id="eximg">
```

Then your css to specify the size should be:

```
#eximg{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Of course, adjusting the numbers accordingly.

If the id attribute is not available and there are surrounding divs, then you can try the following.

html:

```
<div id="eximg-container">
    <img src="./myimage.png" id="eximg">
</div>
```

css:

```
#eximg-container img{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the gtmetrix report mentioned above and let me know the image id? It's for the images http://whiztoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/29-apparition-ep-high-speed-dual-engine-Optimized.jpg (Dimensions: 348 x 131)
http://whiztoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/7-8-team-rc-missile-heli-airstrike-commande-optimized.jpg (Dimensions: 348 x 131)
http://whiztoy.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/tw-742-phoenix-4ch-radio-controlled-rc-airpl-optimized.jpg (Dimensions: 348 x 131)

Comment: No, but I can tell you how :). If you right-click the image and click "Inspect Element" (firefox/chrome just one of these). When the dev mods pops up, see the highlighted tag and look for the "id" attribute, that contains the id.

Comment: I actually did that the first time while looking for the id but it appears that the image has no id attribute. Is there some other way to identify the class which it is associated with? I tried the surrounding classes using the "inspect element" function of my browser but they are all not directly related.

Comment: I have updated my original answer with more information.

Comment: Thanks John. However, the surrounding divs have no mention of the img id.

Comment: They can be of any id. The syntax #id tag for css mean all instances of tag contained within a parent with that id.

Comment: For this issue, I cannot find the corresponding id as all the surrounding divs does not seem to affect the images in question.

Comment: Every image will have a surrounding div. The surrounding div does not have to have the images name in it.